# Converting UTC date from server into local time

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am getting this string as Date from Server

```
2016-06-11T11:14:57.000Z
```

Since it is UTC, I want to convert to my local time.

```
SimpleDateFormat mFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
SimpleDateFormat endFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
mFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+5:00"));
Date date = mFormat.parse(mBooking.startTime);
```

However the date converted to `2:00AM`

Now i don't get it why `11am` is getting converted to `2:00AM`

What wrong am i doing?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Running this code gives me a date of Sat, 11 Jun 2016 06:14:57 UTC. You haven't listed in your question how you are using/reading the value of `date`. Where are you seeing the 2:00am value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you don't set the timezone properly to each `SimpleDateFormat` indeed `mFormat` should be set to `UTC` and `endFormat` to `GMT + 5`, here is what you are supposed to do:

```
SimpleDateFormat mFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
// Set UTC to my original date format as it is my input TimeZone
mFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date date = mFormat.parse("2016-06-11T11:14:57.000Z");
SimpleDateFormat endFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
// Set GMT + 5 to my target date format as it is my output TimeZone
endFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+5:00"));

System.out.println(endFormat.format(date));
```

**Output:**

```
04:14 PM
```